# removing from firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3

I am creating a online ordering service for practice project. Two things I've read into recently is the editing tableview function. when I go to swipe to delete a item it won't take the right item out of the database. Also, if there is only one item in the array and I try to delete it it will make it crash. Anyone have any idea whats going on with this?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    orderNumber.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    itemsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    priceArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    quantityArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

    databaseRef.child("Users/\((authRef.currentUser?.uid)!)/Order/\(orderNumber.remove(at: indexPath.row))").removeValue { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to check the array count before deleting it:-

```
if orderNumber.count > indexPath.row {
 orderNumber.remove(at: indexPath.row)
}
if itemsArray.count > indexPath.row {
 itemsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
}
if priceArray.count > indexPath.row {
 priceArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
}
if quantityArray.count > indexPath.row {
 quantityArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: It still crashes. The problem is occurring in the database reference call. The only thing I get back in the debugger is "Index out of range"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you're removing from `orderNumber` twice. First you're removing here:

```
orderNumber.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

Then you're removing here:

```
child("Users/\((authRef.currentUser?.uid)!)/Order/\(orderNumber.remove(at: indexPath.row))")
```

Any specific reason you're using multiple collections?

Comment: Yea I noticed that and fixed it. I fixed the other issue too but now when I go to delete one it will duplicate and populate the table view with those options again along with the old ones.